# How to convert time results to integer and add or subtract in grafana

Tags: grafana, graphite

I have 3 different time results:

```
averageSeries(stats.timers.type1.mean)
averageSeries(stats.timers.type2.mean)
averageSeries(stats.timers.type3.mean)
```

each one result with different time respectively
5.69 hour
4.56 min
51.22 min

I wish to sum them together, is it possible?

E.g

```
sumThemTogetherFunction(#A,#B,#C) = 6.06 hour
```